# WhiteBox Tool LidarSibsonInterpolation Fails With Error Message

Tags: interpolation, qgis

I'm using the WhiteBox Tool LidarSibsonInterpolation to make a bunch of DEMs, I am very new to WBT and really don't know where to look for solutions, the message is below:

QGIS version: 3.28.1-Firenze
QGIS code revision: fde3b8fbb8c
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.6.0
GEOS version: 3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.1.0, September 1st, 2022
PDAL version: 2.4.3 (git-version: fc5f98)
Algorithm started at: 2023-07-05T09:12:41
Algorithm 'LidarSibsonInterpolation' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'exclude_cls' : '', 'input' : '', 'maxz' : None, 'minz' : None, 'output' : 'C:/Projects/Pacific Ridge/Kliyul/LiDAR/Kliyul_Bare-Earth_LiDAR-LAZ/Temp/Test_2.tif', 'parameter' : 0, 'resolution' : 1, 'returns' : 0 }

WhiteboxTools command:
"C:/WBT/whitebox_tools.exe" -v=true --compress_rasters=True --max_procs=8 --run=LidarSibsonInterpolation --input="." --parameter="elevation" --returns="all" --resolution=1.0 --exclude_cls="" --output="C:\Projects\Pacific Ridge\Kliyul\LiDAR\Kliyul_Bare-Earth_LiDAR-LAZ\Temp\Test_2.tif"
WhiteboxTools output:

---

- Welcome to LidarSibsonInterpolation *
- Powered by WhiteboxTools *
- [www.whiteboxgeo.com](http://www.whiteboxgeo.com) *

---

thread 'main' panicked at 'Error while reading LiDAR file header (C:\Users\Indus\Documents\WBT.).: Os { code: 5, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Access is denied." }', lidar_sibson_interpolation/src/main.rs:403:77
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Failure to run plugin subprocess.
Process completed successfully.
Execution completed in 0.11 seconds
Results:
{'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/Projects/Pacific Ridge/Kliyul/LiDAR/Kliyul_Bare-Earth_LiDAR-LAZ/Temp/Test_2.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Projects/Pacific Ridge/Kliyul/LiDAR/Kliyul_Bare-Earth_LiDAR-LAZ/Temp/Test_2.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Individual files will run, but adding a directory full of laz files fails, the output should be a bunch of DEMs as tiff file format.